# Repair/install Windows 7 without USB or CD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, system-repair-disc

I have encountered the following situation today:

I have a computer with one physical hard drive divided into two partitions. On drive C there were Windows 7 installed, and I wanted to re-install Windows (it was 32-bit, but I wanted 64-bit...)

I could not get any CD or USB device to work with it, so I did the following:

- Mounted a virtual drive with a Windows 7 installation, and I installed Windows 7 on the D drive
- Formatted the C drive
- Afterwards, I knew what was coming to me and was very afraid to restart the computer, yet after setting some settings (setting drive D as the primary and active...) I took the courage and reset the computer, but I wasn't surprised to get a "bootmgr is missing" error...

So here I am, needing to use a repair tool, but without any DVD/CD/usb ... so I grabbed out the hard drive from the computer and inserted it to another computer I have... There I tried using the AOMEI partition assistant to fix the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), move the D drive to the beginning of the physical drive and some other failed attempts...

Afterwards I used VMware, and mounted the entire physical drive, got the "bootmgr is missing" error in the VM, loaded the Windows CD to the VM (I really thought I would get it this time...) and encountered a weird error that I could not fix...

I searched a bit at the web and found no help...

Finally I gave up and went to look for a USB\CD... I got one used Windows 7 repair option and all worked...

But I am really interested of knowing, I had no other choice? Am I limited to the USB/CD when I actually had access to the drive (on the other computer...)? I just cannot accept that...

And another question: Before I reset the computer (after formatting drive C), could I have done anything to avoid this annoying situation?

Comment: More information on your ability to boot to a USB/CD would be required to solve this problem.

Comment: I was able to boot to a cd/usb i just didnt had any... and as i said i want to know how can this be done without usb/cd ... when i am connecting the hard drive to a working computer...

Comment: What exactly was the "wierd error that you could not fix".  The reason your method didn't work was because the boot partition wasn't valid.

Comment: @ramhound: I think he knows this. As I read it, the question is how can one get an install up and running without access to usb or cdrom. For example, in the olden days one could format with the /s option and then put the i386 files on the disk. Certainly OEMs can do it using {magic} and a disk imager.

Comment: @horatio - I am not sure he does understand that.  The problem is that he installed Windows on a secondary computer on the hdd, which meant the boot partition was never actually created, because the boot partition was simply updated on the computer he used.  How an OEM creates and installs their system image isn't magic.

Comment: I think the last two paragraphs speak to it. I think it obvious that OEMs do not resort to magic, it is a proof of concept that there is a way to get a working installer onto a bootable partition without the use of an optical drive or USB. If you know a method to get a working boot partition onto a secondary disk, this might be the correct way to answer the question. HIREN comes to mind but I have never done it personally.

Comment: @horatio i suppose an OEM could just clone the CD and change files, if so then their method,whatever it is, might not help.  Bootable CDs use a standard called El Torito, their boot record is 2048 bytes. Bart's MKIE or MKBT can extract it into a file. A Floppy's is 512 bytes. Nero could take a floppy's or a floppy, and a cd, and make a bootable cd from the floppy. Rufus can take a floppy image or boot sector, and put it to USB. (I know you want CD to HDD, but this background may help you get there)...

Comment: @horatio and this link http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1167812
  mentions a few things about cd to usb.   If there was some kind of virtual cd emulation for DOS or linux, that'd do it. like apparently it seems maybe isostick boots off a usb stick and emulates a cd drive so can take an iso.  I'm actually not sure whether MS uses "el torito" , and whether it does or not might influence your search terms.

Comment: why the downvote ? @horatio i think you and barlop understood me well, and the only thing comes in mind is really trying some boot tools (from the HIREN disk) but im not sure which and how...

Comment: @MatanL dunno why any idiots downvoted you(not intelligent reasons) dont worry about it.hirens is a cd though so you are ok with using a cd just u got no windows one.n even if you could put a windows 7 installation on hard drive,if u could do that then u could put it on cd  or usb. With XP i'd have said really u should not use windows XP if u dont also have an XP CD.With Win7 it has no repair installation off cd so it's not such a loss,the loss is inbuilt.Here is an article about a linux live cd fix a windows mbr http://robert.penz.name/221/mini-howto-restore-windows-mbrbootloader-with-linux/

Answer (score 1):

**Horatio pointed out a flaw in this answer... because in this case the poster couldn't get an <kbd>F8</kbd> menu, his [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) being screwed.**

(But if one could get an <kbd>F8</kbd> menu!)

Windows 7 naturally has a repair option. You hit <kbd>F8</kbd> twice and it's there in the menu.

But if you mean a repair installation, which reinstalls Windows overitself, like Windows XP could. Well, Windows 7 can't even do that off the CD, unless you are already in Windows which makes it a bit useless. (Note: Actually I see a 're-install windows' option at the bottom, second picture. Maybe that is like the old repair installation though possibly only works from within Windows).

But a Windows 7 repair, yeah it's built in.

Windows XP has a "repair from recovery console", and you could install it so it appeared in <kbd>F8</kbd> (though you may have had to push <kbd>F8</kbd> twice to get to it). Windows 7's repair is built in the <kbd>F8</kbd> (<kbd>F8</kbd> twice) menu already. And it has a Windows 7 boot up command prompt (equivalent to the recovery console), and it has a repair thing in there. As well as a system restore option and an option to restore from an image.

I once tried repairing a Windows 7 machine off a CD, and I had to get past an error to do it, whereas the internal one, doing <kbd>F8</kbd> twice, and picking repair, worked fine, and there was no weird error dialog box I had to close.

The Windows 7 repair sometimes needs to be run a few times... That is, until it says no errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not so sure on this one: if the MBR is bOrken, then there is no f8 option AFAIK.

Comment: @horatio oh you're probably right. a screwed mbr, would i suppose affect that

Comment: @horatio is right, i could not get to the f8 option :)

Comment: @MatanL I know a win7 repair installation can't be run off cd/usb, but perhaps  the "startup repair" can be?